# Is there a cross-site RSS feed to the new/top questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, feed

I'm looking for a way to get the recent questions across all stack exchange sites, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/15178/my-it-filter) on the main Stack Exchange site.  Once you do, there's an RSS feed link at the bottom of the page.